# What novel is this quote from?

Tags: story-identification, quotes

I have been trying to figure out what this quote is from. It's almost definitely from a fantasy novel, but I've checked likely books that I'm familiar with (Tolkien, Sanderson) and I can't figure it out. The quote is

> You were right all along, even though I couldn't see it.

This is probably after some tragic event that helps the character realize his blindness to something.

I'm not sure if I'm even remembering this line correctly, so this may be difficult, especially since it's probably an obscure line that I randomly remembered.

Comment: So not *The Sun in Her Eyes* by Paige Toon? "You were right all along. I swear I didn't know she fancied me. I couldn't see it."

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, but good find. Thanks!

Comment: It's a pretty general quote. I can imagine a lot of books having something very similar in.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, I don’t have a lot of hope of finding the specific book. It’s been bothering me because I know I recently read it but I can’t figure it out

Comment: This quote has quite clearly been identified, I'm unsure why this is being voted to be closed?

Answer (score 4):

What I was thinking of is from *Mistborn*:

> I was your god, even if you couldn't see it.

I'm not sure how I changed this to "You were right all along, even though I couldn't see it," but it just dawned on me that it was that line, spoken by the Lord Ruler.

Comment: This carries a completely different tone from what was asked.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, it turns out it wouldn’t have been identifiable if I hadn’t finally thought of it, but that was somehow what I was thinking of. I wish I hadn’t asked the question at this point, because I figured it out so quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I actually missed that this was a self-answer.